# JPA Exception Spec

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a project that used spring-data over JPA for the database layer.
The version used:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

My goal is to handle specific exception(not just Exception like below) when doing the following type of code:

```
        try
        {
            jpaRepository.save(target);
        } catch (Exception e1)
        {
            ....
        }
```

I am unable to find the exception that could be thrown by this code.
I looked at the following link but can't find hints on exceptions thrown.

[http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html#save(S)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html#save%28S%29)

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

That API doesn't throw any exception. You can just catch the runtime exceptions if you want to.

Comment: Thx. I do not want to catch all exception because i want a specific handling. I need any non data exception to be thrown over other call flows not caught by my handler

Answer (score 0):

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
```

is an exception that can be thrown by the code you mentioned .

Comment: Thx. Do you know if this is the only one? Also where did you see that this one is being thrown. Thx in advance.

Comment: i think that it is the only exception that you need to catch cause it deals with lower level persistence exceptions , check this Article : http://www.baeldung.com/spring-dataIntegrityviolationexception

Answer (score 0):

100% Disagree with catching the runtime exception. Something you never want to do, because that's most likely a data integrity issue and can be protected via defensive coding.

You could defensive code to avoid an exception altogether (to my understanding, it's an SQLException). Actually you should always defensive code.

You can however, catch the exception in SQL, if it's an issue of not being able to submit the data to the database like it sounds like.

Also it sounds like if you're talking about an exception of going to the database, it's an SQLException.